# Stop a infinite while loop pressing a key in Matlab

Tags: matlab, while-loop, keypress

I have a while loop, infinite, and I want to stop it when I press a keyboard key.

Pseudocode:

```
While(1)
    do stuff;

    listening for key;
    if key is pressed
        break;
    end
end
```

The function `waitforbuttonpress` makes me press the key, so no luck.

I've found no option on the web.

Comment: You know that Ctrl+C will terminate something, right?

Comment: I want it to terminate the while, not the whole program.

Comment: Check this link out:  http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/waiting-for-asynchronous-events .  Look at the section where you want to set a timeout for `waitfor`.

Comment: @SamuelNLP have you found a solution by now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose if you don't want to resort to [multithreading](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/explicit-multi-threading-in-matlab-part1) (one thread doing the computation in the while loop, another one waiting for input and setting a global sentinel value to break the while loop) you can try to implement breaking the loop on catching a keyboard-interrupt (ctrl-c). This should be possible, albeit in a kinda [hackish way](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/252760).

Answer (score 3):

OK, I know this is a bit late but, I found a solution after a long hunt. When a figure window is focused, you can do this:

```
set(gcf,'currentchar',' ')         % set a dummy character
while get(gcf,'currentchar')==' '  % which gets changed when key is pressed
   do_stuff()
end
```

When a key is pressed while focus is in a figure, it sets the property 'currentchar'. Tested in R2010b.

Answer (score 3):

GUI based solution I found in [Matlab central](http://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/41417#answer_51022)

```
dialogBox = uicontrol('Style', 'PushButton', 'String', 'Break','Callback', 'delete(gcbf)');
while (ishandle(dialogBox))
    statements....
end
```

Comment: it works but you have to add a "drawnow" command in statements